# CMake Cant Find Some Image Libs

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2013, cmake, blender

Im Trying To Compile Blender 2.7 
I was Trying to Generate The Visual Studio 12 ( 2013 ) Project Files 
using CMake But The Problem is That I Get An Error

```
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1089 (message):
  Using HARDCODED libpng locations


Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Found Freetype: C:/Users/Alfrek/Desktop/Blender 2.7/blender-2.71/../lib/win64_vc12/freetype/lib/freetype2ST.lib  
Could NOT find OpenEXR (missing:  _openexr_LIBRARIES OPENEXR_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1172 (message):
  Using HARDCODED OpenEXR locations


Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1191 (message):
  Using HARDCODED libtiff locations


Could NOT find Boost
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1230 (message):
  USING HARDCODED boost locations


Could NOT find OpenImageIO (missing:  OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY OPENIMAGEIO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1928 (message):
  Apple and Windows require pre-compiled libs at:
  'C:/Users/Alfrek/Desktop/Blender 2.7/blender-2.71/../lib/win64_vc12'
```

I got No idea what am I suppose to do

I Have a Windows 7 64 Bit Computer 
and Im Using Visual Studio Professional 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You downloaded the source files but forgot its dependencies. For each platform blender provides its dependencies in its [SVN repo](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BL/).

This is what you need to do:

1. Outside of the blender directory create the folder structure "lib/win64_vc12"
2. cd inside that directory, open your command prompt (assuming you have SVN installed) and type

`svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/win64_vc12`

bear in mind its a huge repo of about 6.5Gb.

When that is done run configure again in cmake and it should work.

Comment: I've done this too, downloaded the SVN repo (it's 8 gigs now!) but still no dice. Seems that cmake needs to know about the directories for the various third party libraries but I'm not sure what's the best way to tell it.

Comment: One silly mistake I made was to put the lib folder in the blender (git) folder. It needs to be on folder up the hierarchy. After that it was able to find all the deps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing a step before trying to run `make full`...

You will need to run the install_deps.sh script or print the list of all main dependencies needed to build Blender (--show-deps option) and install them manually.

Please see the official blender wiki for updated development environment requirements --> https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu

> > Automatic dependencies installation The preferred way to install dependencies under Linux is now to use the install_deps.sh script
> >     featured with Blender sources. It currently supports Debian (and
> >     derived), Fedora, Suse and Arch distributions. When using the
> >     install_deps.sh script, you are only required to install the following
> >     dependencies:
>
> git, build-essential
>
> Then, get the sources and run install_deps.sh
>
> ```
> cd ~/blender-git
> ./blender/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh
> ```